# ¿Cuáles son los algoritmos de compatibilidad?

Tags: python, algoritmos

Quiero hacer "match" entre las preferencias de ciertos estudiantes y las "posibles" carreras profesionales que puedan seguir, qué o cuáles algoritmos de compatibilidad puedo usar? Gracias.

Comment: Hola @AnaMaria. ¡Bienvenida a [es.so]! ¿Podrías agregar más detalles en tu pregunta? Actualmente creo que es un tanto amplia. ¿Qué intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Si te refieres al puro algoritmo de búsqueda se necesita más información hacía como quieres determinar que una preferencia en particular implica que un candidato es apto para una carrera en particular. Si todavía no decidiste estos criterios, la pregunta probablemente es demasiado amplio y las respuestas serían principalmente basado en opiniones.

Comment: @StefanNolde estoy trabajando actualmente en los criterios "psicológicos" de actitudes y aptitudes que quiero usar para hacer el "match", te refieres a eso cierto?

Comment: Por alla va la pregunta, @AnaMariaBenites. El desarrollo de los criterios es más un trabajo para la psicología, sociología o antropología, luego si tengo una definición por este lado puedo pensar en una implementación de matching. Ejemplo: una carrera tiene {3,7} requisitos y {0,n} recomendaciones en las preferencias, mas {0,n} excluyentes. Una persona califica para una carrera si coincide con 100% de los requerimientos,con  90% más 1-2 recomendados o 80% con 3+ de los recomendados. Se deduce 10% por excluyente. Con algo así se puede empezar a trabajar en la implementación.

Comment: @StefanNolde genial, gracias entendí! entonces lo que harías, una vez tengas los criterios de psicología, es crear el algoritmo de compatibilidad desde cero, usando qué lenguaje de programación, quizá Python? Muchas gracias por la información me está sirviendo para observar mejor la idea.

Comment: Para el algoritmo el lenguaje es irrelevante, aun que podría ser más o menos fácil de implementar, todos los lenguajes tienen sus fuerzas y debilidades. Si planificas para una plataforma productiva, no recomiendo python, Python es leeeeento ;) Si quieres hacerlo para ti, hazlo en que te sientes más "en casa".

Comment: @StefanNolde para resolver este tipo de problemas, los cuales son de tipo clasificacion, lo mas pertinente seria usar un clasificador, mas conocido como maquinas de vector soporte. en realidad estaria usando machine learning, o tambien usaria logica difusa.

Comment: @x-rw y eso es el momento en que sería interesante de debatir el tema en el chat, sin embargo ni siquiera hemos tocado la pregunta ya, si hablemos de un sistema que aprende o un algoritmo fijo que esta basado en datos estadísticos o menos en que datos estadísticos existen. Si puedes proveer una SVM genérico que sirve a la Ana con este tema ya antes de definr los parametros de la selección, eso sería el momento de escribir una respuesta (larga).

Comment: @StefanNolde seria un tema extenso, definir las variables. en fin y creo que no deberia ser parte de SOes, por que no es programacion

Comment: Ana, un buen punto, lo que dijo @x-rw, también es una alternativa de basar el matching en valores de experiencia que acumula el sistema sobre el tiempo, en este caso se juntan preferencias, usuarios y carreras y se calculan correlaciones entre personas, sus preferencias y las carreras que siguieron, en que caso se tuviera que definir un método de evaluar el "éxito", por ejemplo basado en tiempo, ingreso o entrevistas midiendo felicidad o otros valores más abstractos, más se necesita un concepto como evaluar estos datos estadísticas.

Comment: @x-rw algoritmos, arquitectura y desarrollo que son requisitos para la programación si son tema para SO si se pueden formular en una pregunta concreta. En esto no estamos aun todavía, por eso revisemos el tema en los comentarios :) "No es tema para una pregunta" no significa que la persona se va con manos vacíos. Saber lo que hay que hacer para llegar a buenas preguntas ya es algo también. ;)

Comment: @StefanNolde planteando un ejemplo: digamos que a pepe le gusta M y B...., a juan le gusta G y R... , a Thiago le gusta T y M ...., y asi sucesivamente, segun los gustos(variables) se puede deducir que pepe es bueno para ser Quimico por decir, entonces Thiago tambien puede ser bueno!!!

Comment: @x-rw Planteando que M es andar en bicicleta. Desde que cantidad de coincidencias quieres asumir esta conclusión? Nunca confía en una estadística que no falsificaste tu mismo, En tu ejemplo también pepe puede ser un químico decente, thiago nulo en todo científico y juan el proximo Niels Bohr... ;)

Comment: @StefanNolde mi ejemplo es un fiasco, bueno se necesita estadisticas confiables, de acuerdo a ello, se plantean variables que no intervengan entre ellas, con eso quiero decir que sean independientes,

Comment: @StefanNolde y me olvidaba este soft es un proy de investigacion, por ello recomendaria python, y R

Comment: @x-rw [chat mejor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53063/npe-o-resultado-vacio)? ;)